# Uploading CSV file with Asian characters specifically "Thai" return ??? on the uploaded file

Tags: php, ajax

I'm uploading csv file with some fields has Thai characters. But it seems the server can't save it properly and changing the characters when uploaded.

I already tried this method

```php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$formFiles=utf8_encode($_FILES);
```

I alredy use this on my header template

```php
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and add this on html head

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This is also set on the form

```html
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' accept-charset="utf-8">
```

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: url,
        data:formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
}).done(function(data) {
```

Then from php I used the typical code of uploading CSV file.

Did I missed something that the Thai character on CSV is returning ??? when uploaded to the server?

Comment: [utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) takes a string as argument while you're passing `$_FILES`, which is an array. That should throw a warning.

Comment: Ill take utf8_encode() off but still the saving file has ????? or any other turn around to make this work?